# Let $ABC$ be a triangle with incentre $I$. A point $P$ in the interior of the triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with incentre $I$. A point $P$ in the interior of the triangle satisfies $\angle PBA+\angle PCA=\angle PBC+\angle PCB$. Show that $AP\geq AI$, and the equality holds if and only if $P=I$.

Please help me.  I couldn't get anything from the question..

Comment: P=1? What is this?

Comment: @vvnitram,  I.e the condition for the equality being true.

Comment: but a point can't be 1 (!)

Comment: @@vvnitram,  let me check the question again.

Comment: @@vvnitram,  Please check the edited version.

Comment: This is 2006 IMO problem 1. Link: http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2006_IMO_Problems/Problem_1

Comment: @vvnitram please delete your comments. The edit has been made

Comment: @@N.S.JOHN, isn't there any other simpler approach?

Comment: It is all right that you havn't found how to begin, but at least, provide a figure. It's done in 5 minutes with GeoGebra, that you will take advantage to us because I see you are interested by classical geometry problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only give a brief explanation to the solution of this problem.

Referring to the diagram below,

[image]

we need the following knowledge:- Let I be the in-center of $\triangle ABC$. The perpendicular bisector of BC and the angle bisector of $\angle A$ will meet at X and X is right on circumference of the circle ABC. In addition, X happens to be the center of the circle passing through B, I, C. Then, XB = XI = XC.

Based on the given, after some calculation, we get:-

∠IBP = ∠IBC - ∠PBC = 1/2 ∠ABC - ∠PBC = 1/2 [∠PBA - ∠PBC] …. (1)

Similarly, ∠ICP = ∠PCB - ∠ICB  = ∠PCB  - 1/2 ∠ACB = 1/2[∠PCB - ∠PCA] …. (2)

Since ∠PBA +∠PCA = ∠PBC +∠PCB , then ∠PBA - ∠PBC = ∠PCB - ∠PCA …. (3)

(1) , (2) and (3) imply: ∠IBP = ∠ICP and therefore BIPC is cyclic. This is equivalent to adding P as another con-cyclic point to the circle BIC. See the diagram below,

[image]

In $\triangle PAX$, by triangle inequality, we have $AP + PX \ge AX = AI + IX$

Result follows after subtracting $PX = IX$ from both sides.

Comment: @ Mick,. and how about $P=I$?

Comment: @NeWtoN P = I means P is right on I. From the diagram, one can see that the blue triangle is degenerated to a straight line only. Then, AP = AI.

Comment: Do we need both diagrams?

Comment: @NeWtoN Two diagrams make the explanation easier to understand.

Comment: @Mick: The circumcircle of ABC is a distraction, it is completely unnecessary for solving the problem.  You say the circumcenter of $CBI$ "just happens" to be on the line thru $AI.$  Are you aware of some theorem that says that the angle bisector of a triangle vertex passes thru the circumcenter of the triangle defined by incenter and opposite edge?  It must be fairly obscure because I couldn't find any such theorem on Wikipedia (looking in subjects such as incenter, circumcenter, angle bisector).

Comment: @J.Heller Let’s start from the circum-circle ABC. The blue line is the perpendicular bisector of BC. It will cut the circle at some point X. Then, $\angle BCX = \angle CBX$. This further means arc(BX) = arc(CX). Next, we join AX. (At this point, we are not sure whether AX will pass through I or not.) Then, $\angle BAX = \angle CAX$ because they are subtending an equal arc. From that, we conclude that AX is actually the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$.

Comment: @Mick I'll repeat: you don't need the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$.  What you do need to do is to show that the line thru $AI$ intersects the circumcenter of $\triangle CIB$.  In your comment, you did not show that $X$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle CIB$.

Comment: @J.Heller Continued. In addition to XB = XC, we also have XI = XC because both $\angle XIC$ and $\angle XCI $ are equal to $0.5\angle BAC + 0.5\angle ACB$ (via $\angle BAX$). This makes X the circum-cneter of $\triangle CIB$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given at the linked website is not clear and also wrong, 
so I'll write a clearer and correct solution here.  To really
understand this, you probably need to draw a figure (as I did when
writing this).

Let $J$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle CIB.$  The key part of this
problem is proving that $IJ$ is parallel to $AI.$  Since $JC,$ 
$JB,$ and $JI$ are radii of the circumcircle, their lengths are all 
equal to the same value (that is, $|JC|=|JB|=|JI|=R_{CBI}$).  Triangles
$JCI,$ $JBI,$ and $JCB$ are isoceles, so $\angle JCI=\angle JIC,$ 
$\angle JBI = \angle JIB,$ and $\angle JBC=\angle JCB.$ Using 
the fact that $I$ is the intersection of the angle bisectors of
$\triangle ABC,$ the sum of the interior angles of quadrilateral $CIBJ$ is
$$
  \begin{align}
  & 2(C/2+\angle JCB) + 2(B/2+\angle JCB) + (\pi - 2\angle JCB) \\
  & \qquad = C+B + 2\angle JCB + \pi \\
  & \qquad = \pi-B-A + B + 2\angle JCB + \pi \\
  & \qquad = 2\pi - A + 2\angle JCB \\
  & \qquad = 2\pi
  \end{align}
$$
so $\angle JCB = A/2$ and $\angle JIB=A/2+B/2,$ which is 
$\pi - \angle AIB.$  So $AI$ is parallel to $IJ.$

Let $P=I.$  Then $\angle PBA=B/2,$ $\angle PCA = C/2,$ 
$\angle PBC=B/2,$ and $\angle PCB=C/2$ (so the condition of the problem
is satisfied).  When $P=I,$ $\angle PBA=\angle PBC$ and $\angle PCA=\angle PCB.$  Moving $P$ from $I$ means setting $\angle PBA = B/2-s,$ 
$\angle PBC=B/2+s,$ $\angle PCA=C/2-t,$ and $\angle PCB=C/2+t$ for some
angle increments $s$ and $t.$  
The condition
$\angle PBA + \angle PCA = \angle PBC + \angle PCB$ is now equivalent to
$s=-t.$  So when decreasing $\angle PBA$ by $s$ (for some $s\in (-B/2,B/2)$),
$\angle PCA$ must be increased by $s.$  This means 
$\angle PBI = \angle PCI = s.$  So a classical geometry 
theorem says that quadrilateral $BPIC$ is cyclic, meaning $P$ is on
the circumcircle of $\triangle CBI,$ meaning $|JP| = |JI|.$

Finally, the triangle inequality applied to $\triangle APJ$ shows that 
$|AP|+|PJ| \geq |AJ|=|AI|+|IJ|.$  Since $|PJ| = |IJ|,$ $|AP|\geq |AI|$
(with equality only when $\triangle APJ$ is degenerate, that is, when
$P=I$).

Comment: @@J.H..Heller,  Could you please provide me with a figure?

Comment: This is actually a very hard question.  Based on looking at some of your more recent questions (for example, chord of length 16 in radius 10 circle), this question is a little beyond your level right now.  Once you've mastered more plane geometry (circumcircles, inscribed circles, inscribed angles, cyclic quadrilaterals), you might want to come back to this question.  Then it would only take a few minutes to draw your own figure on paper to follow along with the solution.

Comment: @@J.Heller  However, I know all those concepts (cyclic quadrilateral, inscribed angles, inscribed circles, etc).. But, I.just couldnot draw a fig. so, If you please provide me a figure, it would be helpful. Thanks..

Comment: There is a difference between "knowing" and "mastering".  Someone with a very good grasp of all these concepts could easily draw a figure of this problem on paper in a few minutes.  It would take me longer than this to create a good quality electronic figure.